# "Copy default content element" from other language than default

Tags: typo3

hope someone has a idea.

I run into a challenge on a multi language typo3 site.

The default language is english and there are two spanish languages. Now, after I've translates the first spanish, I would like to copy this to the second one.

So basicly I would like to say "Copy spanish #1 content element", instead of "Copy default content element"

In TYPO3 4.5 there was a quite nice extension "fl_langtranslate", but this not gonna work anymore in > 6.0.

Anyone have I idea or solution for that? I am wondering that TYPO3 is not gonna do this out of the box.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this issue quite often, I'd suggest to think about a language-fallback.

Using TypoScript, you can define which language to fall back if your translation isn't available.
Here's an example:

Here's an example for English (en) as 0, Spanish (es) as 1 and Mexican Spanish (es-MX) as 2.

```
# Don't fall back to another language. If it's not translated, the user has to switch the language.
sys_language_mode = strict

# english language
sys_language_uid = 0

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
    config.sys_language_uid = 1
[global]
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
    config.sys_language_uid = 2
    # Try es-MX first and if not available, try es-ES. If that's not available, too, this page is not translated.
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback ; 2,1
[global]
```

You could also create a 3rd language and call it Spain Spanish (es-ES) and use it for content that's just for people living in Spain and just never use the id 1 for creating links - just for content-translation ;)

Comment: This is very close to what i'm looking for. I can definiftly use this for a first workarround. Thank's a alot for that!

Answer (score 0):

The most extensions does not work in 6.0 because of some API-functions which has been changed. So perhaps check your PHP-Errorlog. Usually it is easy to replace the API-function. There is t3lib_div::int_from_ver noted at http://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_6.0_Incompatible_Extensions_F

use t3lib_utility_Version::convertVersionNumberToInteger() instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.

I already fixed that. It's in line 6 of ext_localconf.php from extension fl_langtranslate.

I replaced line 6:
if (defined('TYPO3_version') && t3lib_div::int_from_ver(TYPO3_version) > 4005000) {

with:
if (defined('TYPO3_version') && t3lib_utility_VersionNumber::convertVersionNumberToInteger(TYPO3_version) > 4005000) {

and also tried to totaly remove it. But the extension still not using the configured languages for translation.

Is there no out of the box solution for this? Or any other extension you maight heard of?

Thanks alot for help!

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 version 7.5 this feature is implemented, you can choose in a selectbox near the button "Copy default content elements" from which language you want to copy the content elements.

Ext. fl_langtranslate now should work with TYPO3 6.2 but has a bug, if you removed the prefix "Translate to..." (if the "l10n_mode" is not "prefixLangtitle"):

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['header']['l10n_mode'] = '';
```